# Questions about clamp meters

Tags: multimeter, meter

Are clamp meters as accurate as multimeters?

Could I replace a multimeter with a clamp meter?

What can clamp meters do that multimeters can't?

What can multimeters do that clamp meters cant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clamp meters are good for measuring higher currents. Standard multimeters can typically measure current but require breaking the circuit and are good for measuring amplitudes less than an amp ( milli or micro amps).  Some clamp meters have almost as many features and ranges beyond current by attaching leads-  allowing you to measure voltage and ohms. Make a list of your requirements and then compare your list to meter specifications and capabilities.  The only defining requirement for me is if I need to measure milliamperes,  which typically clamp meters don’t have good resolution and standard multimeters are better suited for.

Comment: There are clamp on mA meters with exceptional resolution.  They are typically used for current-loop process instrumentation measurements.

Answer (score 0):

Clamp meters can only detect change in current in a conductor without making electrical contact or needing to put it in series with the load. They can also detect common mode current in a pair of conductors (like a ground fault).

That's all.

Which means it is not a substitute for a multimeter *at all*.

In DC mode they will drift because it integrates all current changes over time which naturally accumulates errors.